# How to aggregate and delete duplicate rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I made a mistake when defining a unique key in one of my SQL tables, and this has resulted in duplicate rows of data being entered into the table.

The rows of data look like this:

```
A, B, C, D, E, created_datetime, last_seen_datetime
```

The unique key is defined across `(A, B, C, D, E)`. Some of these columns are nullable, and I had forgotten that unique keys do not work when one or more columns can be `null`.

What I want to do is perform two operations:

- Find the minimum `created_datetime` and maximum `last_seen_datetime` and set the existing duplicate rows to have these values
- Delete existing duplicate rows

Then I want to:

- Redefine the unique key so that duplicates cannot be inserted

In order to do this I will:

- Delete the existing unique key
- Change the columns so that none are nullable
- This will require setting any currently null values to something which is non-null but represents a null value
- Re-creating the unique key. Now that the columns are not nullable, it will in future enforce uniqueness

I am not sure if this is possible in pure SQL.

I haven't made much progress towards solving this. I had an idea that perhaps a `group_by` operation could be used to find duplicate rows.

```
select
  count(*),
  A,
  B,
  C,
  D,
  E
from
  my_table
group by
  A, B, C, D, E
having
  count(*) > 1;
```

This does indeed appear to be working but I am now unsure of how to use the found duplicate rows to perform the remaining work.

Comment: which sql database are you using

Comment: Duplicate rows - can these involve null values? Show us some sample data, so we can understand how you identify duplicates.

Comment: I _strongly_ suggest that you add sample data, both before and after, to make the question more clear and to avoid potential confusion.

Comment: I am using Postgre however I would prefer a database agnostic solution, if possible.

Comment: _something which is non-null but represents a null value_... such solutions tend do cause problems forever.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track there, perhaps try this: (no promises)
Please do make a copy of your table somewhere before you try this - and don't commit until you've checked it works, for my sanity please!

Step 1: Find the minimum created_datetime and maximum last_seen_datetime for each set of duplicate rows:

```
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, 
MIN(created_datetime) AS min_created_datetime, 
MAX(last_seen_datetime) AS max_last_seen_datetime
FROM my_table
GROUP BY A, B, C, D, E
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Step 2:  Update the existing duplicate rows:

```
UPDATE my_table AS t

JOIN (
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, 
MIN(created_datetime) AS min_created_datetime, 
MAX(last_seen_datetime) AS max_last_seen_datetime
FROM my_table
GROUP BY A, B, C, D, E
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS dup ON t.A = dup.A AND t.B = dup.B AND t.C = dup.C AND t.D = dup.D AND t.E = dup.E
SET t.created_datetime = dup.min_created_datetime,
    t.last_seen_datetime = dup.max_last_seen_datetime;
```

Step 3: get rid of the duplicates:

```
    DELETE FROM my_table
    WHERE (A, B, C, D, E, created_datetime, last_seen_datetime) NOT IN (
    SELECT A, B, C, D, E, 
    MIN(created_datetime) AS min_created_datetime, 
MAX(last_seen_datetime) AS max_last_seen_datetime
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY A, B, C, D, E
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    );
```

Step 4: redefining a unique key for the table:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP CONSTRAINT your_unique_key_name;
ALTER TABLE my_table
ALTER COLUMN A INT NOT NULL,
ALTER COLUMN B VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
ALTER COLUMN C VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
ALTER COLUMN D INT NOT NULL,
ALTER COLUMN E VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE my_table ADD CONSTRAINT your_unique_key_name UNIQUE (A, B, C, D, E);
```

Obviously I don't know what your table is called, so don't forget to change that when you try this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options to work around this:

I would create a new table with the correct table definition without deleting the original table; say the origin table is `table_a` then I would create a new table let's call it `table_a_dummy`

```
create table table_a_dummy as (
   ....
)
```

We can coalesce the null values to an "x" if it's string, or if it's integer then perhaps we could coalesce them as a "-1". Any values that you would think fits better.

Then I use the row_number function to get the first value of duplicated data. Then, I'd insert that into a `table_a_dummy`

Assume the data types are string:

```
with cte1 as (
  select
    COALESCE(A,'x') A,
    COALESCE(B,'x') B,
    COALESCE(C,'x') C,
    COALESCE(D,'x') D,
    COALESCE(E,'x') E,
    created_datetime,
    last_seen_datetime
  from
    table_a
),

cte2 as (
  SELECT 
    *,
    row_number() over(partition by A,B,C,D,E order by created_datetime asc, last_seen_datetime desc)
  FROM cte1 
)

INSERT INTO table_a_dummy
(A, B, C, D, E, created_datetime, last_seen_datetime)
SELECT
  A, B, C, D, E, created_datetime, last_seen_datetime
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1
```

review `table_a_dummy` that should have contain cleaner version of `table_a` without risking to remove the original table.

Once you have reviewed the `table_a_dummy` and you feel it's correct -- then we can safely remove the `table_a`

```
drop table `table_a`
```

and rename `table_a_dummy` to `table_a`

```
ALTER TABLE `table_a_dummy`
RENAME TO `table_a`;
```